# Avoiding to repeat field names when using INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a very large number of fields, and the table is being populated by a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query. Since the number of fields is so large, I get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
                column1,
                colunm2,
                colunm3,
                ...
                column200)
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       ...
       column200
  FROM SomeView;
```

The above is cumbersome and error prone to maintain, so I'd prefer if it was possible to have some kind of "natural insert" where the field names in the `SELECT` clause are mapped to the fields with the same names in the target table.

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       ...
       column200
  FROM SomeView;
```

Which is syntactically correct, but relies on matching the order of the fields, which is even more error prone, so what to do? Am I overlooking a much more obvious third option?

Clarification: the purpose is to make it easier to maintain the code in the long run. We will be updating this statement many times, so I am looking for a way to make it more readable and easy to modify.

Comment: Your second query is the answer to your question. I don't see how this could be any shorter ? You need to declare source and destination - how else would a mapping be made ?

Comment: The first option with specifying all columns, might be a bit harder to write but is the best and the least error-prone.

Comment: The mapping could be done the same way a natural join works - by using the field names from the ``SELECT`` statement.

Comment: Unless the order of columns in both the tables is same, i dont think that it would be possible. Other workaround would be to use SSMS to create a `INSERT` query for you and just use those columns. This way the order will not matter.

Comment: Best and least prone is to generate the command from database dictionary.

Comment: I've just added a clarification: my main goal is making the code easy to maintain. Writing it in the first place isn't too hard, but I worry about how others are going to maintain it later.

Answer (score 2):

You can write yourself a query that generates the insert statement (or even executes it at the same time) using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = 
    STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + name 
            FROM sys.columns 
            WHERE object_id = object_id('MyTable') 
          FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO MyTable (' + @cols + ') 
               SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM SomeView'

--print the statement and copy/paste it for saving or using
PRINT (@sql)

--or just execute it right here
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I see two big disadvantages here: readability is lower and you may get runtime errors, that would otherwise have been caught earlier.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do to speed up the above is to drag the `Columns` value in SSMS onto a new query and the editor will display all of the column names in a row.

So

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT
```

Drag Columns

```
FROM SomeView;
```

Your columns will appear as a comma separated list, some may be missing the [] if needed but it's quicker than typing them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My issue is that this will be a statement that I am sure we are going to edit many times, so I am looking for a way to make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this very low tech solution:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, colunm2, colunm3, ..., column200)
SELECT               column1, column2, column3, ..., column200
  FROM SomeView;
```

It breaks most code formatting guidelines, but at least it is possible to tell how the mapping is done without having to count the fields in two places.